# Rails Google Maps Turblinks not working in production mode

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

Have a problem loading google maps in production mode. in development mode all works.

application.html.erb

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='+Rails.application.credentials[:google][:maps]   %>
```

In my view.html.erb

```
<% provide :head_tags do %>
    <meta name="turbolinks-visit-control" content="reload">
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
         initMap()
        });
    </script>
<% end %>
<div class="container">
  <h2>OUR LOCATIONS</h2>
  <div id="map">
  </div>
</div>
```

function initMap() is available.

However in production mode map is not showing up and throwing error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: initMap is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>
```

Who has a solution?

Comment: Where's `initMap` defined? you say it's available, where? can you run `initMap()` on the dev tools console? does your javascript_include_tag includes the right api key on production? I don't think you whould call initMap() when the document is ready, you should let the api call that function when it's ready, check the callback parameter https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Comment: The map div is only on one page and yes there I can call initmap

Comment: Api key is correct